# Using twitter bootstrap in bookmarklets - CSS affecting rest of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, namespaces, bookmarklet, dynamically-generated

I am injecting Twitter Bootstrap into a bookmarklet I'm making, but the CSS is overriding the existing stylesheets on the page. I only want to it to apply to the markup generated by the bookmarklet. Is this at all possible? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2):

Have the bookmarklet create its own `<object>`, then inject Bootstrap and the markup into its `data` attribute as a `data URI`:

```js
void
( 
  function disable_and_replace_bootstrap() 
    { 
    "use strict"; 
      
    var css_markup = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>'; 
    var bootstrap_markup = "<h1 class='h6'>Hi</h1><h6 class='h1'>Bye</h6>";
    var newobj = document.createElement("object");
          
    newobj.setAttribute("width", "100px");
    newobj.setAttribute("height", "100px");
    document.body.innerHTML = bootstrap_markup;
          
    newobj.setAttribute("data", "data:text/html,"+css_markup+bootstrap_markup);
    document.body.appendChild(newobj);
      
    }() 
)
```

**References**

- [In modern browsers, is there any security limitation for JavaScript bookmarklets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693140/1113772)
- [How To Make a Bookmarklet For Your Web Application](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/)
- [Debugging iPad / iPhone web based apps using Firebug lite bookmarklet](https://xomino.com/2015/01/05/debugging-ipad-iphone-web-based-apps-using-firebug-lite-bookmarklet/)
- [Mobile Perf Bookmarklet](https://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/mobileperfbkm.php)
- [Mozilla Bug 530308 - Disallow `<object data="javascript:...">` for XSS prevention](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530308)
- [Dynamic style - manipulating CSS with JavaScript](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript)
- [Supported HTML](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the css to apply only to your bookmarklet. Because bootstrap css is compiled from less files you can easy modify it and compile.